# restrict weight painting on occluded/hidden geometry

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights

I am weight painting, part of my geometry is obstructed visually.

[image: setup]

Using the add brush, I paint on the visible vertices. (The rest of the geometry [the other cube] is behind the the visible cube.)

[image: painting]

But then I have also painted on the vertices which I can't see. I don't want this.

[image: result]

Using the 2D Falloff, I paint throught the geometry (as if it was X-Ray). Using the Sphere Falloff, I paint around corners. With both settings I often paint on vertices which I am not seeing.

How can I **only** paint on the geometry, which I can see?

Comment: This was the default behaviour in 2.7x.

Comment: it should not, you must have enabled the 2D Falloff option (N panel > Tool > Brush > Options)

Comment: @moonbots Under NPanel>Tool>BrushSettings>Falloff>Falloff Shape are the options *Projected* and *Sphere*, which I showcased in the last image. I am using 2.82.7, have I missed anything?

Comment: Ok sorry I can't test the latest versions  ;)

Comment: I am using first version on the official download page, which version are you using? I just want to weight paint a 2.8 file.

Comment: mine is 2.8.0, may 2019, I'm on a old Mac System, so I can't use the new versions, I'll be able soon I hope

Comment: I downloaded 2.8.0, but it is the same problem. If I disable 2D Falloff (and use Sphere) I can still paint around corner if my brush is to big. See the image on the bottom right. I only want to paint on visible vertices. [Besides, I would like to use the 2D Falloff like in Blender 2.79]

Comment: weird because I don't have this problem. By the way, what do you mean when you say that you use Sphere Falloff? I don't see that option...

Comment: @moonboots https://i.imgur.com/70dMMeI.png
The options for falloff in 2.82a are sphere or projected. Projected needs to be used with "Frontface Falloff" to prevent OP's issue, but even that is a poor substitute for occlusion if you're painting objects with multiple submeshes, concave, or overlapping geometry. 

It's not an adequate solution, but I still use 2.79 for weight painting, although 2.8x has been making progress.

Comment: I still don't have latest versions, so still hard for me to understand, you don't have a solution for Leander?